# How to restore default windows 10 video codecs

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui

I installed [XVID codec](https://www.xvid.com/) for working with video editor (Sony Vegas Pro). And "Movies & TV" app does not to show AVI with this code, now. After that I uninstalled XVID but Movies & TV still not shows AVI files, it plays only sound from video.

How can I restore default Windows codecs for Movies & TV app?

P.S.: Windows 10 build 1607  x64 version.

P.P.S.: Windows Media Player shows this files correctly.

Comment: Installing the XCID Codec wouldn't have touched the codecs supported by the UWP `Movies and TV` which means the problem is more likely the video itself.

Comment: @Ramhound, you are wrong. UWP player try to use it.

Comment: I suggest you uninstall it then just install it again.  You can install it again by simply running `Get-AppxPackage *zunevideo* | Add-AppxPackage` within an elevated PowerShell prompt.  I maintain your problems with the video your attempting to play, is using a non-default codec, though.

Comment: @Ramhound, thank you, i'll try. All my xvid videos was played ok until l install xvid codec.

Comment: http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_8_codecs.html

Comment: @Moab, I don't like to install any third-party codecs to OS, especially k-lite mods!

Comment: @Ramhound, unfortunately `Get-AppxPackage *zunevideo* | Add-AppxPackage` is not helped to me. Movies and TV still does not show xvid video.